# How to spool to different files from nested scripts?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is it possible to spool to different files from nested script?
I have one script that calls another script. The first script spools everything to an output. And I want to save only certain parts of the second script in a different file.

But when I stop spooling in the second script, it stops completely, and I don't know how to start it again to make it continue spooling in the first file.

For example having these 2 scripts, the second Select to MY_TABLE doesn't get spooled.

**firstScript.sql**

```
prompt --------------Start firstScript--------------
set pagesize 0
set heading on 
set feedback on 
set timing on
set time on
set echo on
set verify on

spool testFirstScript.sql

select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') from dual;

@secondScript.sql

select * from MY_TABLE where Id = 1; -- This doesn't get spooled.

spool off

prompt --------------End firstScript--------------
```

**secondScript.sql**

```
prompt --------------Start secondScript--------------

spool testSecondScript.sql

select * from MY_TABLE;

spool off
prompt --------------End secondScript--------------
```

---

**The spool output:**

**testFirstScript.sql**

```
11:28:23 SQL> 
11:28:23 SQL> select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') from dual;

  CREATE TABLE "S1"."MY_TABLE"                                             
   (    "ID" NUMBER,                                                               
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(30)                                                            



1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.08
11:28:24 SQL> 
11:28:24 SQL> @secondScript.sql
11:28:24 SQL> prompt --------------Start secondScript--------------
11:28:24 > 
--------------Start secondScript------------- 
11:28:24 SQL> spool testSecondScript.sql
```

**testSecondScript.sql**

```
11:28:24 SQL> 
11:28:24 SQL> select * from MY_TABLE;
         1 Test1                                                                
         2 Test2                                                                

2 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.36
11:28:24 SQL> 
11:28:24 SQL> spool off
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run a script with `@` the contents of that file are embedded in the parent, so from SQL*Plus' point of view you're just running one long script. SQL*Plus commands are not localised to the child script.

You would have to start spooling again after the embedded script, with the [`APPEND` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve043.htm#sthref2324), e.g. in `firstScript.sql`:

```
...
spool testFirstScript.sql

select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') from dual;

@secondScript.sql

-- restart spooling
spool testFirstScript.sql append

...
```

With that change, `testFirstScript.sql` now has:

```
16:28:14 SQL>
16:28:14 SQL> select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','MY_TABLE')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "STACKOVERFLOW"."MY_TABLE"
   (    "ID" NUMBER,
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(


1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.26
16:28:14 SQL>
16:28:14 SQL> @secondScript.sql
16:28:14 SQL> prompt --------------Start secondScript--------------
16:28:14 >
--------------Start secondScript-------------
16:28:14 SQL> spool testSecondScript.sql
16:28:14 SQL>
16:28:14 SQL> select * from MY_TABLE where Id = 1; -- This doesn't get spooled.
16:28:14   2
16:28:14 SQL> spool off
```

And testSecondScript.sql still has:

```
16:28:14 SQL>
16:28:14 SQL> select * from MY_TABLE;

no rows selected

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
16:28:14 SQL>
16:28:14 SQL> spool off
```

You might also want to `spool off` before `@secondscript`. And `set long 32000` (or some other big number) so you see the whole dbms_metadata output, though I realise this is just an example.

Comment: Thanks! - Sorry for my ignorance, but is there other way I could invoke a script other than with @?. It is an example, but I am still learning on what kind of things I should set, I don't fully understand the LONG property, I may have to open a separate question for that.

Comment: @Dzyann - [`set long`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#sthref1912) determines how many characters SQL\*Plus displays for LONG (and CLOB) values; it defaults to 80, so your DDL was cut of part way through. With a big value you'll see the whole thing. And, not really; [you can use @@ or start](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve002.htm#sthref1063) but they are similar. (I tend to use @ since you can use that from the command line, but there are slight differences).

Comment: Alex - I understand that, but I don't know what I should do when my output length is unknown. I posted a question about here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267215/how-to-set-long-depending-on-output-length

Comment: @Dzyann - I think Justin covered it *8-)