# How to SET LONG depending on Output Length?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

I need to save the output of several **DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL** calls to different files with **SPOOL**.

**GET_DDL** returns **CLOB**, but its length can vary. Some of the calls will return few characters, while others will be very large.

I don't know how I could set [LONG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699121) using the Length of my **CLOB**.

I have tried something like this:

```
   SET pagesize 0

   VARIABLE ret_val CLOB 
   VARIABLE lengthRet NUMBER       

   select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') into :ret_val from
   dual;

   --this doesn't work I get ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified.
   --Also Length returns length in characters not in bytes.
   select LENGTH(:ret_val) into :lengthRet from dual;

   --This doesn't work either, I get:
   --SP2-0268: long option not a valid number
   SET LONG :lengthRet
```

How can I set LONG depending on the length of ret_val? 
Should I try doing that, or instead should I set [LONG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699121) to its maximum size (2,000,000,000 bytes)?

Finally, is my understanding that CLOB can be of any length, am I right? Would it be possible that even using LONG maximum size my script could be truncated?

Comment: I've also just set it to the max when I needed to.  If you need to increase it for this kind of thing, what benefit is there to setting it "exactly" ? (ans: not much) .. Just over kill it and put your attention on something more worth while :)  lol

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:367980988799

Comment: Yes: a CLOB doesn't have any upper limit, so could theoretically blow over that LONG limit .. :)

Comment: @Ditto - Well I don't know much about SQLPlus and this setting, but, in theory if my scripts are never bigger than say, 1000 bytes and I set LONG to 2,000,000,000 wouldn't that be "bad"? At least like killing a fly with a sledgehammer? I really don't know, I am just asking what is the best approach :)

Comment: @Dzyann - if you know the max size of your scripts is only 1000, I'd just `set long 10000` and call it a day then ... point is, set it to something sufficiently large. You implied it was REALLY large and you didn't know .. ergo, GO BIG .. ;)  If you know you don't need *that* big, no problem .. pick a smaller number, large enough for your task.  (and if all else fails what Politank posted might help chunk a very large script down if needed) ;)

Comment: There is no penalty to setting `set long xxxx` to a larger value than you need.  All that does is to tell SQL*Plus to stop reading (and printing) the LOB after a certain number of bytes.  If the LOB is shorter, SQL*Plus will naturally stop earlier.  You'd generally just pick a value that is larger than you'd ever expect to need.  If you want to ensure no truncation, though, I'd tend to be writing PL/SQL that runs on the database server and uses `UTL_FILE` to write out the data.

Comment: @JustinCave - I am writing scripts to update a large number of files, I have read about UTL_FILE, but I have no way to test it, since I am writing the scripts and later the DBA with access to the server will run them on the server. I am concerned because I don't know for real how long the scripts could be  and I was worried about a penalty of too big a LONG. If I use UTL_FILE and DBA is running my scripts on the server where on the server the files will be generated? If you could post your comment and maybe elaborate a bit on how you use UTL_FILE, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Ditto - Well I actually have no idea what the size of scripts are. For certain I know one is above 90k chars. I used 1000 as a simple example. Also thanks for pointing out what Politank meant, I don't how I didn't realize that, having read the post in the past and even used it in the past. It must be late, My bad there!

Comment: @Justin: Good points, I suspected that, but wasn't 100% sure so didn't want to make that claim ;) Glad a name I recognize showed up to confirm. :)

Comment: @Dzyann: you should / need a test environment. It's odd that you have no environment to test/run this stuff in. Talk to your DBA and ask about that.

Comment: @Ditto - Well with spool I have no issues. The problem is with UTL_FILE. Having a better understanding of spool limitations I can go and talk to my DBAs and hopefully they will give me a way around it.

Comment: Have you considered an export (expdp) of the metadata instead of writing your own mechanism?

Comment: @AlexPoole - expdp can be used for saving the DDL for Oracle objects? From what I read it seems is for exporting data from Tables.

Comment: You can export [data, metadata or both](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL838). Saving to a binary dump format rather than a text script, but if its for recreating the schema in another DB, export/import is simpler. (But your master object creation scripts are already held in source control, right? *8-)